# java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.util.List in Spring project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I have the code:

```
public Student LoginStudent(Student student) {

    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().begin();
    String hql = "select stu_id,name from  student  where username = "ap@gmail.com";
    students = (List<Student>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(hql).uniqueResult();

    if (students.size() > 0) {
        return students.get(0);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am getting error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

I searched google, somewhere suggests,

```
return ((BigInteger)LoginStudent.get(0)).longValue();
```

But how I have to use this?

Comment: When you run the sql `"select stu_id,name from  student  where username = "ap@gmail.com"` what is the result you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

Change hql to

```
String hql = "from Student where username = 'ap@gmail.com'";
students = (List<Student>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql).list();
```

the javadoc for [`uniqueResult`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult%28%29) says

> Convenience method to return a single instance that matches the query, or null if the query returns no results.

But you need a `List<Student>` to retrieve, so use `list()`.

Comment: I have used list().....I am getting error:---java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to com.student.pack.Student

Comment: return students.get(0);-----this line

Comment: `students` is a `List<Student>`, and you return the first element of it which is a `Student`. There's no `BigInteger` here, unless you manually cast it. Don't cast an object which is not instance of a `BigInteger` to this type. And use proper naming in code, if you write `hql` then use HQL, if you want to use SQL, then write `sql`. I will add the line to execute HQL instead of SQL, and read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31681771/573032) if you still want to use SQL.

Comment: @Salini: sounds like you didn't use Roman's change to the hql, try that first.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the line from

```
students = (List<Student>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(hql).uniqueResult();
```

to

```
students = (List<Student>) (sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(hql).uniqueResult());
```

Give a try, it should work if uniqueResult() returns a list of student objects

Answer (score 0):

To get your hql to work you need to do something like this:

```
Student student = null;

sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().begin();
String hql = "select stu_id,name from  student  where username = :username";

Object[] result = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    .createSQLQuery(hql)
    .setParameter("username", "ap@gmail.com")
    .uniqueResult();

if(result != null) {
   // manually convert your selection into a Student
   student = new Student();
   s.setId((Long) result[0]);
   s.setName((String) result[1]);
}

return student;
```

The reason you have to do this is because you are selecting certain field from Student in your hql query. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select

Answer (score 0):

Or declare a constructor so your query works like this:

```
select new Student(s.stu_id,s.name) from  Student s where...
```

That should do it.